# Showare 6: page.customerGroup returns null in twig template CustomerGroupRegistrationPage

Tags: shopware6

We have a problem, accessing the customer group in the customer group registration page. Dumping the page object, the customerGroup is displayed:

```
{{ dump(page) }}
```

Dumping the customerGroup returns null:

```
{{ dump(page.customerGroup) }}
```

See attached screenshot. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a deviation of the usual naming conventions for getters in `CustomerGroupRegistrationPage`. Usually the property would resolve to a call of `getCustomerGroup` but in this case the getter is named `getGroup`. However you can just call the getter directly.

```
{{ dump(page.getGroup()) }}
```

Alternatively this should work as well:

```
{{ dump(page.group) }}
```